# Корень в слове "пылесос"

Tags: словообразование, морфемика

Какой корень в слове "пылесос"?

Answer (score 5):

У слова "пылесос" два корня: *пыл* и *сос*. А *"е"* — соединительная гласная.

Answer (score 5):

**пылесос** = устройство для всасывания пыли

> пыль/ + соc/а/ть -> пыл/е/сос/

Соответственно корня два:  *-пыл-* и *-сос-*.